# How can a MapView be embedded into an existing Activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I am working on an Android Tablet application, one of the Class involves displaying a bunch of text and data lists along with a Map. So far all my text and data components are in place and only the Map needs to be inserted, The usage of the MapView means I need to extend MapActivity instead of just extending Activity.

What is  the solution to this? Should I rewrite my Class extending MapActivity or is there any way to write a separate class with MapActivity extended for the MapView and then embed that class within my original Class.

If the latter solution is feasible how how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is no way to include a `MapView` without extending a `MapActivity`. 
 I guess rewriting your class will be the simplest way.

Comment: this might not even be much of a change, beyond implementing isRouteDisplayed and changing extends Activity to extends MapActivity

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a simple solution, all you need to do is have a nested subclass inside your main class for the MapView that extends MapActivity so that does the trick.